# Does SvelteJS convert third-party libraries code to plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, npm, svelte

If SvelteJS compiles everything in your code to plain JavaScript does this mean that third-party libraries' code will also be converted to plain JavaScript and remove the ever so problem of npm modules vulnerabilities for JavaScript  frameworks, or I'm getting this all wrong

Comment: Yes, you're getting this all wrong. Vulnerabilities are not removed by transpiling to "plain javascript". Or what kind of npm vulnerabilities did you think about? (Btw, I don't think svelte does transpile your dependencies unless you specifically tell it to)

Comment: Svelte just cares about the components you write, it doesn't even transpile, Rollup/Webpack do the transpiling via Babel (usually), e.g. neither Svelte nor Rollup/Webpack or Babel are doing anything to fix vulnerabilities... The "plain" javascript you're talking about just refers to the fact that after compiling you do not have any Svelte specific code in your bundle, e.g. not external library to load...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Svelte compiles your components. That's all.

Comment: My understanding was that it converts the entire code into simplest form. Is this possible to do? If yes , will that do any good?

Comment: It compiles your components. Open https://svelte.dev/repl and click on 'JS output' to see what it generates. It doesn't touch your JavaScript, that's not its job

Answer (score 1):

Transpiling code will usually transpile (and preserve) the security vulnerabilities too.